# Rails after_create callback to update a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users, groups, and memberships. I have a has_many through relationship set up between users and groups using the membership join table. What I am trying to do is set up an after_create callback that adds a new record into the memberships table whenever a user creates a new group, that way the creator is automatically a member of the group.

Right now, a user can create a group, but the group will display having 0 members, and the user will have to join the group. How can I automate that part with the callback if I'm trying to update the membership Model from the Group controller?

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_groups, class_name: "Group"
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
```

group.rb

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

membership.rb

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

groups_controller.rb

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  after_create :set_membership

  def create
    @group = current_user.groups.build(group_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'You have a new Group!' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_membership
    end
end
```

The set_membership part is where I'm completely lost. I just need to grab the created group's id and use it to create a new membership (with current user id).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll move `set_membership` to `Group` model (`active_create` is a model callback, so it will not work in a controller), and create the `Membership` there, like this:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  after_create: set_membership

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  private
  def set_membership
    Membership.create!(user_id: user_id, group_id: id)
  end
end
```

Comment: That worked, I just had to repace current_user.id with id, since I guess you can't call current_user in the model. The user id would have been set in the Group upon creation, so I can just use that.

Comment: You are right, i just updated the answer. Although notice that i used `user_id` (i guess you meant that) instead of `id` (which has the group id).